# Building a multishell model - How can I duplicate a group of parts, but still edit children and have selective visibility?

Tags: collections, instances, visibility

I'm a complete novice and I need to ask for help. I am using Blender to combine existing STLs of wargaming miniatues into multishell components for 3d printing.

I have a number of parts (weapons) which are all childed to an empty, and the empty is childed to an arm part in order to position the weapons to match the arms - I can then toggle visibilty of the weapons to select the one I want for the current model. But there are many arm parts in different poses, and each one will need a copy of the empty childed to it. I can do all that, but I also need to be able to make changes to all the empties and their childed parts at once.

The goal is to have a 'master' empty where any changes I make (the childing a new weapon and positioning it relative to the empty) will be disseminated down to all the other copies of the empty. But at any given time, I will only want one weapon from one copy visible (excluding the master). Ideally, the visibility of an empty and its child weapons would be collectively slaved to the visibility of the arm part, but then the visibility of individual weapons would be slaved to the master.

I have attempted this using collections and instancing but I ended up with a blob where all guns were apparently merged and not positioned to match the empty. I also tried linked duplicates but that only copied existing child parts. I'm fairly confident the soultion is one/both of these, but I'm not sure what to search for to get around this problem.

I can also imagine a solution where I only have one master empty with the weapons, and that gets snapped to other 'wrist' empties, but I would need to ensure it snapped to the correct roation/location for each wrist.

I'd be grateful for any help on how to achieve this, even it's just a pointer on what tools to look into.